# Constantly execute javascript code on some webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bots

What I would like to achieve is this:
I load some webpage and here are some clickable contents like buttons, clickable divs etc. What I want to achieve is: I want to constantly run javascript code that will click some buttons then after that wait for 15 seconds, refresh the page and repeat. (Yeah, some kind of a bot). I know how to achieve clicks etc. I will manage with the code but how to achieve such a functionality? I know that there was some extension for Chrome to do such things, but I can't remember now. Would be grateful for some tips.

I tried creating my own html file and dynamically loading whole html of the page I want the bot to work on into div of my html file. Something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--<div id="siteloader" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;"></div>​-->
    <div id="siteloader"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#siteloader")
            .html('<object data="http://linktowebpage.com"/>');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is: it creates an iframe and it is so small and I can not make it any bigger (it's like 150x150 px).

As I say I would like to do it without doing such stuff (creating my own page etc.).

Would be grateful for any tips ;)

Comment: I think you need something like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Take a look at `setTimeout` and/or `setInterval`.

Comment: Use jQuery [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to load the page and [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to call the function repetitively.

Comment: The problem is, I do not have access to the server-side stuff. So I can't get it using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to run your JS on some third party page. With `<iframe>` it won’t work because you could read page contents, at best.

You could write a code that does everything and run it in console. But, for instance, if you wanted to use jQuery, a page would have to have it. So the safest option in this case would be to have it written in pure JavaScript. The downside and disqualifying issue, as I guess, is you have to run it everytime after refresh.

In your case you could use a tool like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome) or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) which allows you to run your JS per domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to do the function repeatedly and [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to load the page.

Check below example to get started.

```js
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  $.get("http://linktowebpage.com", function(data) {
    $('#siteloader').html(data);
  });
}, 60000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Specified URL will be loaded every 1 minutes</div>
<br>
<div id="siteloader"></div>
```

Comment: And what about refreshing the page part?

Comment: But tell me how to run the code. I can write my own code it is not a problem, I know JS pretty well, tell me how to run it on external webpage as I described. I guess I will try to use these extensions provided above.

Comment: Check this [**link**](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe.php) on how to access iframe contents.

Comment: Interesting, will check it out. Do you know how to make an iframe bigger? Because it loads in a frame (using .html <object data = ...) but it is small, I would like to see whole page in a frame.

Comment: @Pugazh, but that is a read-only access, I believe, so clicking anything on a page is out of a question.

Comment: Okay I managed to make the iframe bigger finally, lol, it actually needed to add a styling to iframe and not to the div I put iframe in. The page overally is not read-only I can click on the page, of course (as explained above) however I can not get to the .txt (actually .html file) on the server to get it using Ajax request.